# why is my for looping running twice?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

This is for a google extension that covers selected text with an image on a tumblr post

As you can see below, I also have a hide display and button (not finished but not relevant). 
I've been testing this code out with three tumblr posts that contain the word "women". It's functional but it creates duplicates so in my case i'll have 6 images and 6 buttons instead of the three of each.

```
//search these elements
var busca = document.getElementsByTagName("div");

//search for this word in those elements
var searchText = "women";
var found;



for (var i = 0; i < busca.length; i++) {
    if (busca[i].textContent == searchText) {
        found = busca[i];
        //if spoilers found 

        //erase paragraph
        found.style.display = 'none'; 

        var img = document.createElement("img");
        img.src = "https://i.imgur.com/miZBLCk.jpg";

        // add image
        found.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(img);


        var btn = document.createElement("BUTTON");
        var t = document.createTextNode("CLICK ME");
        btn.appendChild(t);

        //adds button
        found.parentNode.parentNode.appendChild(btn);

    }
}
```

Can anyone figure whats wrong with loop?

Comment: It means you have 2 divs in your page

Comment: use an id instead of a tagName. This way you know exactly where it's going to happen.

Comment: Thanks everyone! It's been a long day, I just realized I had my class as div instead of what I actually wanted - paragraphs. I will use the ID suggestion as well. ty